# Android github action with an Apple Silicon M1 runner

Tags: android, github-actions, android-espresso, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I want to run on a github action some Android espresso tests.
I need to test arm64 as well and I expect much faster runtime for performing slow espresso tests as well on an Apple Silicon M1 runner.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with an self hosted M1 runner on a 8GB Mac mini.
I was forded to modify action https://github.com/hannesa2/action-android/releases/tag/0.1.4.10

Now I can use

```
  - name: Android Emulator test
    uses: hannesa2/action-android/emulator-run-cmd@0.1.4.10
```

Please see full pull request https://github.com/hannesa2/paho.mqtt.android/pull/449

The performance is amazing fast and it's much more stable (only on x86 I've to re-trigger espresso several time)

#### Runtime arm64

[image]

#### Runtime x86

[image]